# Oracle - can't drop an editioning view

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I have an Oracle 11gr2 DB, and I have created an editioning view called TEST which I'd now like to drop.

I run

```
DROP VIEW TEST;
```

as DBA, and get the following error:

```
ORA-04045: errors during recompilation /revalidation of USER.TEST 
ORA-00001: unique constraint violation (SYS.I_EV2) violated
```

I know the editioning view has errors: that's why I want to drop it.`SYS.I_EV2` looks like some kind of system constraint, and I don't want to touch it.

The only reason I want to drop the editioning view is that I want to create another view on the same underlying table, and I get an error message if I try and create a second editioning view on the same table.

Comment: have you tried this drop command after setting correct edition using alter session? that might help.